# How to change an objects x and y coordinates by degrees?

Tags: javascript, math, object, expression, coordinates

I'm working on some coordinates function to my canvas in HTML5, and I want to make a function which can move an object by degrees.
My dream is to make a function which works like this:

```js
box.x=10;
box.y=10;
// now the box has the coordinates (10,10)
moveTheBoxWithThisAmountOfDistance=10;
degreesToMoveTheBox=90;
box.moveByDegrees(moveTheBoxWithThisAmountOfDistance,degreesToMoveTheBox);
// now the box.x would be 20 and box.y wouldn't be changed because
// we only move it to the right (directional 90 degrees)
```

I hope this makes any sense!
So my question is:
How does the mathematical expression look like when I have to turn a degree into to coordinates?

Comment: You need to convert the degrees to radians

Comment: I guess I know your problem. Maybe you are looking for Angular Distance: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_distance) and Angular Diameter: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter)

Comment: `moveTheBoxWithThisAmountOfDistance` Explicit naming gone too far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `sin` and `cos` to convert an angle and a distance into coordinates:

```
function moveByDegrees(distance, angle) {
  var rad = angle * Math.pi / 180;
  this.x += Math.cos(rad) * distance;
  this.y += Math.sin(rad) * distance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A little spelling mistake, but nevermind, it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

That's it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix , all the math is described :)

Also beware that if you need multiple sequential rotations (i.e. you do continuous animation), it's better to recompute x' and y' from initial ones and not just previous. Not doing so will result in rounding errors accumulation, and after some thousand rotations the  result will become too rough.